# Is there a suitable definition in categories for a closed continuous function in topology?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Working in the category of topological spaces is it possible to give a 'categorical' definition for 'a closed continuous function'? I mean something like: 'a closed continuous function' is an arrow in **Top** such that ... My intuition tells me that it is not so, but on the other hand this intuition has often turned out to be arrogant and wrong.

Comment: I remember asking similar questions in topology to my professor (who is a category theorist ). I also remember that he told me before that there were attempts to approach topology using category theory only, but the approach was not fruitful because it is suspected that there are properties/defintions about topological spaces that we really need the open sets to state them and not just the continuous functions (the morphisms in $Top$)

Comment: I also suggest a possibly better title: "A categorical definition for closed continuous functions"

Comment: @Amr. Thank you for answering. I am afraid that my intuition is right. That will feed its arrogance... I followed your advice to change 'map' into 'continuous function'.

Comment: The closed subsets are precisely the regular monomorphisms... in the category of _Hausdorff_ spaces. $\mathbf{Top}$ is too large to have any convenient properties as an abstract category.

Comment: @Zhen Lin. Thank you. It happens quite often that it is enough to focus on Hausdorff spaces. So this is a valuable tip.

Comment: This question reminds me of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66279. By the way, I agree 100% with Zhen Lin's comment above.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but your question reminds me of this: the most general definition of a proper map between topological spaces $f: X \to Y$ is that it is "universally closed", meaning that for any topological space $Z$, the map $\mathrm{id}_Z \times f : Z \times X \to Z \times Y$ si closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with products and coproducts. Let us denote by $1$ the terminal object. We assume that $\hom(1,-) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is faithful. The motivating example is $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Top}$.

*Definition.* A *global element* $a$ of an object $A$ is a morphism $a : 1 \to A$.

*Definition.* An object $A$ is called *discrete* if every map of global elements $\hom(1,A) \to \hom(1,B)$ is induced by a morphism $A \to B$. An object $A$ is called *codiscrete* if every map of global elements $\hom(1,B) \to \hom(1,A)$ is induced by a morphism $B \to A$.

*Definition.* A *[Sierpinski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space) object* $S$ is a an object which has two global elements $x,y$ and which is neither discrete nor codiscrete.

In the case of $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Top}$, these elements $x,y$ are distinguished by the property that $\{y\}$ is open, but $\{x\}$ is not. Of course there is also another, isomorphic Sierpinski space with the roles of $x,y$ exchanged. But for us only the first is the correct one.

Now the task is to distinguish these two Sierpinski objects from each other, for general $\mathcal{C}$. The correct $S$ has, for *every* set $I$, a morphism
$$\cup : \prod_{i \in I} S \to S$$ such that a global element of $\prod_{i \in I} S$, i.e. an $I$-indexed tuple consisting of $x$ and $y$, is mapped to $y$ if and only if there is at least one $y$ in the tuple. And the correct $S$ has a map
$$\cap : \prod_{i \in I} S \to S$$
such that only the constant tuple $y$ is mapped to $y$ *only* then $I$ is finite.

I don't claim that such an object $S$ exists for every $\mathcal{C}$, but that this is a *property* in the language of categories which may or not be satisfied by $\mathcal{C}$, and it certainly holds for $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Top}$.

After having characterized the correct Sierpinski object $S$ as well its two global elements $x,y$, we are able to define open and closed subobjects, motivated by the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space#Continuous_functions_to_the_Sierpi.C5.84ski_space) that the Sierpinski space classifies open subsets in the case of $\mathsf{Top}$.

*Definition.* An *open subobject* of an object $A$ is a morphism $U \to A$ which fits into a pullback diagram

$$\begin{array}{c} U & \rightarrow & 1 \\ \downarrow &&~~ \downarrow y \\ A & \rightarrow & S. \end{array}$$

If we take $x : 1 \to S$, we obtain the notion of a *closed subobject* of $A$. Note that we can define the union of an arbitrary family of open subjects, as well as *finite* intersections, using the operators $\cup,\cap$ from above.

*Definition.* Let $f : A \to B$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$. It is called a *closed morphism* (resp. *open morphism*) if for every closed (open) subobject $Z \to A$ the composition $Z \to A \to B$ has an [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28category_theory%29) factorization $Z \to Z' \to B$ for some closed (open) subobject $Z' \to B$.

Let me mention that with these definitions it is easy to obtain the *[rigidity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56887)* of the category of topological spaces $\mathsf{Top}$. Roughly, this means that the "concrete structure" of the objects can be recovered in the language of category theory. The underlying set of $A$ is just $\hom(1,A)$, and its topology consists of the images of $\hom(1,U) \to \hom(1,A)$ for open subobjects $U \to A$.

The definitions may also be applied to the category of posets $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Pos}$, where $x$ and $y$ can not be distinguished from each other. Therefore the automorphism class group of $\mathsf{Pos}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, the automorphism mapping $(X,<)$ to $(X,>)$.

Edit: Freyd had already shown rigidity in his [book](http://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html) on abelian categories, Chapter I, Exercise G. He offers a surprisingly simple distinction between the "correct" and the "wrong" Sierpinski object: If every point of a space is open, this space is discrete. This is not the case if every point is closed.

Comment: Thank you! I, as always, will need time to capture this, but it makes me quite curious. Small note about your dream concerning the future of mathematics (mentioned in your profile): the right spelling is *burden* (not 'burdon') ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Given a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ and letting $\tau(X)$ denote the open sets of $X$. Consider the morphism $f^{-1} : \tau(Y) \to \tau(X)$ -- the fact that this is a morphism is exactly what makes $f$ continuous. Now look at the collection of closed sets of $X$ and $Y$, what does it mean for $f$ to be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Topological spaces can be defined as pairs $(X,¯_X)$ where 
$¯_X$ is the closure operator as a function from 
$P_X$ (the power set) to 
$P_X.$ Then a closed continuous map $f:X→Y$ is a map which respects the
closure $¯$, i.e. the compositions 
$$¯_Y∘Pf:PX→PY→PY$$
 and $$Pf∘¯_X:PX→PX→PY$$ are equal.

Comment: You have used the notion of a closed subset in the power set of the underlying set - this is not "allowed" in the question, which asks for a purely category-theoretic characterization within $\mathsf{Top}$.