# "Absolute retracts" in arbitrary category

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, terminology

Is there a standard notion of something like "absolute [retract](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/retract)" in arbitrary categories that generalizes [absolute retracts](http://planetmath.org/absoluteretract) in topology?

I am mostly interested in categorical approach to Hausdorff compacts.  In the category of Hausdorff compacts and continuous maps, i can define *absolute retracts* as objects such that every monomorphism of that object to another one [splits](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism), i.e. is a split monomorphism.  Is this definition standard?  Does it work well to generalize topological absolute retracts for non-compact spaces?  If not, is there a better name for objects from which every monomorphism splits?  Is there a better definition of "categorical absolute retracts"?  Is there a standard name for the [full subcategory](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/full+subcategory) generated by the class of all "absolute retracts"?

Comment: In order to do that, you should expressed "closed" and "normal" as pure categorical properties... I'm not sure it is possible. What the motivation behind your will of generalization ?

Comment: Then my question would be: is there a categorical term for the objects such that every monomorphism from them splits? I've found a [purely topological definition of a closed interval](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123760/topological-characterization-of-the-closed-interval-0-1/168110#168110), which i am satisfied with, and i was thinking about stating it in categorical terms.

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in [injective objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object).

Comment: You might be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450193/ where I gave a categorical description of open and closed embeddings. This way you should also be able to define normal spaces, and then absolute retracts. However, I don't know if anything of this is standard, and therefore it will just be a comment. (You explicitly asked for standard notions.)

Comment: See Definition 9.6. of [this book](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), which I think partially answers your question at the beginning.